# Including seperate file in original file causes original file not to run

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, nasm

Basically, I am using NASM to create simple .COM files to use. For one of the files(ttcb.asm), it starts out by clearing the screen. This is done by calling a routine in another file, so I used `%include 'video.asm'`. This includes the file as expected. When I include this file, nothing else following the `%include` statement in the original file(the file that included `video.asm`) will be executed, even if I don't call the separate routine. I also see that the code in video.asm is automatically getting executed. But when I remove the `%include` statement, everything runs properly. I've even tried removing **everything in video.asm**, but it still did not work. Then I tried making video.asm a blank file, and it worked, but that will be pointless. Then I tried moving the include statement around, but that failed as well. Is there any solution to this, or do I have to insert the subroutine directly into the original file?

**ttcb.asm:**

```
[BITS 16]


section .text

%include 'video.asm'

call screen_clear

jmp $    ;should've frozen the .COM, but it didn't, meaning it failed to execute.


section .data

welcomeMsg db 'Welcome to the TitaniumCube ©.',13,10,0,'$'

section .bss
```

**video.asm:**

```
;===================================
;-----------------------------------
;Clears the screen to black
;No input or output
;-----------------------------------

screen_clear:
mov ah,0Fh
int 10h
push ax
mov ah,00
mov al,00
int 10h
pop ax
mov ah,00
int 10h
ret

;-----------------------------------
;===================================
```

Comment: Where will it return to after the last statement?

Comment: It is supposed to return to where the routine was called. In one of my older .COM's that I deleted, this would work properly, but I cannot get it to work now.

Comment: Make sure you compile it as a DOS platform binary and make sure you specify the code start address. The start address should be at the `call screen_clear` instruction, and not at the start of `.text` section.

Comment: @Jay-Sorry it took so long to respond, but would your solution be possible by rearranging the lines of code, or do I have to use `[ORG]`? I'm kinda new to assembly.

Comment: When I moved the `%include` to the bottom of the `.text` section and moved the `call screen_clear` above the `section .text`, it worked perfectly. Is this what you meant @Jay? If so, can you convert your comment to an answer so it is clear to everyone and I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For COM files, use `org 100h` to specify the binary base address. The `.text` section will be the code start address. So put all functions *after* the main program block ends.

Below is the code. Compile with: `nasm -fbin -o ttcb.com ttcb.asm`

```
[BITS 16]


org 100h ;set base address. must be 100h for COM files


section .text ;start of code is always start address for COM files

call screen_clear

mov ax, word welcomeMsg ;put welcomeMsg offset in register AX
;if above "org 100h" isn't specified, the above instruction would produce:
;"mov ax, 001Ch" instead of "mov ax, 011Ch"

;jmp $    ;should've frozen the .COM, but it didn't, meaning it failed to execute.
int 20h ;terminate program

%include 'video.asm'


section .data

welcomeMsg db 'Welcome to the TitaniumCube ©.',13,10,0,'$'


section .bss
```

PS) Under pure DOS, there's no `©` (copyright) character.